# Derivative of $f(x) = (\sin{x})^{|\cos{x}|}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I got this function:
$$f(x) = (\sin{x})^{|\cos{x}|}$$
and I want to determine for all points in the domain of the function whether (one-sided) derivative exists, and if it does, then what is it. Can you expand this function so that it is continuous?

What I got:

The domain is $x ∈ R$

Now I can derivate the function like this:
$$ f'(x) = |\cos{x}|\cdot(\sin{x})^{|\cos{x}|-1}\cdot(-\cos{x})\cdot 1 $$
but is this enough? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should $f(-\pi/3)$ be? And no, you did not compute the derivative correctly.  You should try using logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: won't you get the base $\sin x$ negative for $\pi < x < 2\pi?$

Comment: @abel I will, but why is that a problem?

Comment: Domain is not all real numbers...!

Comment: @Mykybo $(-\text{irrational number})^{\text{irrational number}}$ may not always be in $\Bbb R$, e.g. $\left(-\tfrac1\pi\right) ^{1/\pi}=0.375...+i\,0.584...\notin\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Workaholic wow, you are right, thanks, I have no idea how this is the first time I heard about it.

Comment: @Workaholic, happy new year!

Comment: @abel Thank you so much, happy new year to you too! Hope you enjoyed your holidays. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will look at the $$y = (\sin x)^{|\cos x|}, 0 < x < \pi.$$ you can check that $y$ is symmetric about $x = \pi/2.$  therefore it is enough to consider the function on $0 < x < \pi/2.$  on this domain we have $$y = (\sin x) ^ {\cos x}\to \ln y = \cos x \ln (\sin x) \to \frac{dy}{y} = -\sin x \ln(\sin x) \,dx+\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x} \, dx $$

clearing the last equation should give you $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the domain $0 < x < \pi/2.$  you can extend the derivative as an odd function about $x = \pi/2$ all the way to $0 < x < \pi.$

Comment: Where did the $\cos^2{x}$ in $-\sin x \ln(\sin x) \,dx+\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x} \, dx$ come from? The derivative of $ln(\sin{x})$ is $\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$, then we need derivation of the $\sin{x}$ itself, which should be $-\cos{x}$?

Comment: @Mykybo, derivative of $\ln(sin x)$ is $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ not $\frac 1{\sin x}.$  it is called the chain rule for derivative.